# Docpad Multiple Content Blocks

Tags: docpad

I would like to have several content blocks in my documents to output them in the templates at different positionions (eg aside and sections). In this case I do not want to work with partials. As I need some marginal jade formating, I can not put these into the Metadata as this is not rendered (as far as I tested it). Are there any other ways?

For illustration in the doc:

```
text1: p my first textblock
text2: h1 my second textblock
```

and in the template:

```
section document.text1
aside document.text2
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? This is exactly what I want to do.